# How to automatically escape variables in a Zend Framework 2 view

Tags: security, view, escaping, zend-framework2

A lot of times in a Zend Framework 2 view I'll be calling `$this->escapeHtml()` to make sure my data is safe. Is there a way to switch this behaviour from a blacklist to a whitelist?

PS: Read an article from Padraic Brady that suggests that [automatic escaping is a bad idea](http://blog.astrumfutura.com/2012/06/automatic-output-escaping-in-php-and-the-real-future-of-preventing-cross-site-scripting-xss/). Additional thoughts?

Comment: what do you mean by switch behaviour from a blacklist to a whitelist? Do you mean, stop escaping the text even though escapeHTml is called? You could just not call the function to not escape the text.

Comment: Right now you blacklist variables, ie pick and choose what you want to be "secured". I'd like the behaviour to be the reverse, ie pick and choose what I want to be raw (unescaped) output.

Answer (score 4):

You could write your own `ViewModel` class which escapes data when variables are assigned to it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Robs comment, I extended the ZF2 ViewModel as follows:

```php
namespace Application\View\Model;

use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\View\Helper\EscapeHtml;

class EscapeViewModel extends ViewModel
{
/**
 * @var Zend\View\Helper\EscapeHtml
 */
protected $escaper = null;

/**
 * Proxy to set auto-escape option
 *
 * @param  bool $autoEscape
 * @return ViewModel
 */
public function autoEscape($autoEscape = true)
{
    $this->options['auto_escape'] = (bool) $autoEscape;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Property overloading: get variable value;
 * auto-escape if auto-escape option is set
 *
 * @param  string $name
 * @return mixed
 */
public function __get($name)
{
    if (!$this->__isset($name)) {
        return;
    }

    $variables = $this->getVariables();
    if($this->getOption('auto_escape'))
        return $this->getEscaper()->escape($variables[$name]);
    return $variables[$name];
}


/**
 * Get instance of Escaper
 *
 * @return Zend\View\Helper\EscapeHtml
 */
public function getEscaper()
{
    if (null === $this->escaper) {
        $this->escaper = new EscapeHtml;
    }

    return $this->escaper;
}
}
```

In a Controller it could be used like this:

```php
public function fooAction()
{
    return new EscapeViewModel(array(
        'foo' => '<i>bar</i>'
    ));

    //Turn off auto-escaping:
    return new EscapeViewModel(array(
        'foo' => '<i>bar</i>'
    ),['auto_escape' => false]);
}
```

**Question:**
I would appreciate it if soemebody would comment, if this is best practice or if there is a better and ecp. more efficient and resource-saving way?